# Prescribing a Riemannian metric along a given geodesic

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ be a finite $C^2$-curve in the plane which does not intersect itself.  Let $p(z)$ be a second-degree polynomial in $z \in \mathbb R^2$.  Can we construct a Riemannian metric $g$ along $\gamma$ such that

- $\gamma$ is a geodesic of $g$,

$\gamma$ has length 1, and

$p(z)$ is the 2-jet of $g$ at $\gamma(0)$?  (i.e. this prescribes $g$ and its first and second derivatives at $\gamma(0)$) **Edit**:  As per Sergei's comment, assume that $p$ is chosen so that $\gamma$ does in fact solve the geodesic equation.

I think so, and my sketch of an argument follows the proof of existence of Fermi coordinates in reverse.  I haven't worked through this in detail yet, though, because I'm more concerned about the next question:

Let $\gamma$ and $\eta$ both be finite curves $[0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ which do not intersect themselves, and such that $\gamma(0) = \eta(0)$ and $\gamma(1) = \eta(1)$ with no other intersections (i.e. $\gamma \cup \eta$ is a piecewise, simple, closed $C^2$-curve in the plane).  Can we construct a metric $g$ as above?  Note that if so, $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ will be conjugate points along $\gamma$.

Comment: If you prescribe the first derivatives of $g$ at $\gamma(0)$, the geodesic equation gives you a specific expression of $\gamma''(0)$ in terms of $\gamma'(0)$. So you cannot make any given curve a geodesic.


Comment: 1) Are you constructing the metric $g$ as $p$ times the Euclidean metric? 2) If you define $p$ along $\gamma$ so that $\gamma$ is a geodesic and has length 1, what else is there to do?

Comment: For the second question, do you again have some $p$-jet condition?  If not, can you construct the metric you want just by diffeomorph-ing a connected open neighbourhood of the two curves onto an open subset of a suitably-metrized sphere?  (There will be a few cases depending on whether the angles of the curves at their meeting-points are acute-acute, acute-straight, acute-obtuse, etc.)

Comment: I don't see any issues with constructing the metric in the second case, except that everything has to match up properly at the endpoints.

Comment: What regularity do you want from $g$? If $g$ is $C^2$, the geodesics must be $C^3$.
